# Show an $L^2$ function is $L^1$

Tags: analysis

I am trying to show that for all $f \in L^2([0,2\pi])$, we also have $f \in L^1([0,2\pi])$ by Cauchy-Schwarz.

I really couldn't see how Cauchy-Schwarz could be applied here. If I apply it to $(f,f)$, I still would have an $L^2$ norm. Can you give me some hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\int |f(x)|dx = \int 1\cdot|f(x)|dx$. Can you apply Cauchy-Schwarz to this?

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish I had thought about this. Could you also explain why this fails for $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$? (Is it because of the unboundedness of $\mathbb{R}$ since there is a constant $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ in the inner product of $L^2$?)

Comment: As you have figured out yourself, the argument fails for functions defined on $\mathbb R$, because the function $f\equiv 1$ is not integrable there. Even though, in order to show that the statement itself actually fails, one has to give an example of a function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, but $f\notin L^1(\mathbb R)$. If you play around a little with functions like

$$ f(x) =\begin{cases} 0, & x\in(-\infty,1), \\ x^{-\alpha}, & x\in[1,\infty),\end{cases} \qquad \alpha\in\mathbb R,$$

you will quickly find such a function.